# How to get path name of a file in Rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I working on a Rails script, and I need to get path name of the file uploaded, I did the same in Laravel recently, it was quite easy, here is the code I used at that time:

```
$img->getPathName();
```

but I don't have any idea how to do the same in Rails.

Comment: Please show your code. How did you upload the file? What libraries, if any, did you use? Is the file being stored locally, or on cloud services? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also can you please provide parameter details you get at development.log file?

Answer (score 0):

This guide is having various ways to get pathname, may it helps you:

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html